# How to extract stock apk from TWRP backup?

Tags: backup, mount, twrp

I installed TWRP recovery on my phone and backed up the system, data and boot partitions before installing CM12.1.

I would like to extract one stock apk (FM radio) from the backup on a Linux system. How do I mount the system.ext4.win file?

Comment: It's a simple `ext4` image so mounting it as an `ext4` partition is enough. Just remember that CM12.1 may not have all required libraries/drivers to actually launch your stock app.

Comment: The extension is .ext4.win. Somehow I'm not managing to mount it with `sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop system.ext4.win ./Mount`. I'm getting a generic error (wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error). I'm aware that CM might lack drivers but trying it doesn't carry risks.

Comment: Do you have access to a PC running 7-Zip? If so, just open the file in 7-Zip and you are done. No need to mount it.

Comment: Finally it was not necessary to mount it. It was sufficient to extract it with `tar -xf archive_name` but the app doesn't install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered that it was not necessary to mount it. It was sufficient to extract it with `tar -xf archive_name` but this particular app doesn't install.

Answer (score 7):

Rename the `system.ext4.win` file to `system.ext4.tar`and extract it.
If your
*TWRP backup* is not in compression method, you will directly get to the `/system` folder or if your *TWRP backup* is in compression method, you will get a file named `system.ext4` which you'll have to just rename it to `system.ext4.tar` and extract it to `/system` folder