# Extract data from nandroid backup

Tags: root-access, backup, nandroid

As I am not using an official version of cyanogenmod, I cannot restore my Data partition, that I was forced to wipe. I did the backup with TWRP thus, it is in the nandroid form. However, when I try to restore the Data partition, CM does not boot. As a workaround, I could mount (or extract) data from the nandroid, and place it in the `storage/emulated/0/` directory.

The TWRP backup consists of files named `data.ext4.win000` to `win003`, with a data.info and a recovery.log.

I already tried extracting the backup with Titanium, but it needs the donator's version to do that.

If it is necessary, I do have root access. I am on OS X, and my phone is SM-G800F kminilte. Since ext4 is compatible with Debian, I can use that as I do own one too.

---

A very tedious workaround would be to revert to stock ROM, flash the Data backup, get data and reflash CMmod, but that is something I want to avoid to do at all circumstances, unless there is no other way to do.

Comment: There are several other [apps to deal with Nandroid backups](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup#group_142) you might wish to take a look at.

Comment: Did you try the answers here: [How to extract stock apk from TWRP backup?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/115020)