# Extracting data from a TWRP backup

Tags: backup, twrp

How can I extract individual files from a backup created with TWRP? I’ve come across [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/128260/116537), which is about extracting an APK from the system partition. However, I want to extract files from `/data`, which gets split across several files in the backup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The files created by TWRP with a `*.win` or `*.win???` extension are tar archives. If a partition gets split across multiple files, each is a tar archive in its own right.

There is a slight difference, depending on the TWRP version used to create the backup. The watershed seems to be 3.2.* or before.

**If the backup was created with an older version:**

The files are in standard TAR format which any Unix-like OS should understand. Simply rename each file, giving it a `.tar` extension, and open it in your favorite archive tool (Engrampa on Ubuntu MATE has worked well for this).

**If the backup was created with a recent version:**

The file format uses custom TAR extensions, which the standard tar tools cannot process, see https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/issues/1472. You need to extract the file with TWRP’s own flavor of `tar`:

- If the backup is no longer on the device, copy the required file back. (Should work on any device with TWRP, regardless of where the backup was created.)
- Boot into TWRP.
- `adb shell` into the device.
- `cd` to a folder where you want to store your extracted files (I recommend creating a temporary one, extracting files there and then copying them to their intended destination – gives you some security against accidentally overwriting parts of your filesystem).
- Extract those files with TWRP’s custom tar build:

  - `tar -tvf data.ext4.win000` will list all files in that particular backup archive (use `grep` to search for something particular).
  - `tar -xvf data.ext4.win000 path/to/file` will extract the specified file. In my case, TAR removed the leading `/` from file names and placed the extracted file in the current folder, with the path appended.

Another option would be to build TWRP’s custom tar tool on a system of your choice, then do the extraction on that system.

Comment: On Ubuntu opening them with double click errors: format not supported but I can extract them with `tar -xvf` And on Windows I can't extract them with 7-Zip unfortunately.

Comment: tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'TWRP.security.e4crypt'
the command line client is successful in extracting files, but spams the above warning.

Comment: I don't know what's changed in the last few years, but extracting a specified file to a relative path isn't working for me using the custom tar that is in twrp-3.6.2_9-0-hima.img from inside an adb shell. Without the leading slash on the specified file's path, I get an error that the specified file is "not in archive". *With* the leading slash, it extracts the file to the absolute path. Using the -C argument also makes no difference.
I've provided more complete examples here: https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/issues/1472#issuecomment-1221440111

Answer (score 21):

`cat data.ext4.win??? | tar xvfi -`

What this does is concatenate each file matching the pattern `data.ext4.win???` and then pipe the concatenated files to tar for extraction. the `-` as the filename tells tar to extract from stdin. The i option ignores zero blocks which will be in between each archive file concatenated.

In this example I used the ext4 formatted data partition. Change `data.ext4` to match the partition you are extracting.

Disclaimer: This has not been tested in a windows environment.

For a less hacky solution found [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-extract-multiple-tar-ball-tar-gz-files-in-directory-on-linux-or-unix/)

`for f in data.ext4.win???; do tar xvf "$f"; done`

This is a bit simpler without relying on the ignore zeros option of tar to operate properly

Edited to reflect davidgo's comment.

31-Jan-2020 Edited to reflect Code Bling's comments.

17-Feb-2021 Edited to reflect alecxs's comments.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129757/discussion-on-answer-by-johnathon-havens-extracting-data-from-a-twrp-backup).

Answer (score 1):

Try [BinWalk](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk), it's a fast, easy to use tool for analyzing, reverse engineering, and extracting firmware images. and for more information take a look at this [Quick-Start-Guide](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).

Answer (score -1):

Just extract it with winrar to a folder on desktop and that's it