# Is possible to extract app from original KDZ file?

Tags: nandroid, lg-g4

I want to extract the Call/SMS App and the Remote controller App to install them in to a lineage OS version of the same phone.
I have a original KDZ and nandroid made it with TWRP bootloader.

The phone is not rooted. I was not able to do this.
The phone is an LG G4 H815 (T-Mobile)

Comment: Should be possible using [KDZZ](https://www.xda-developers.com/kdzz-build-flashable-zips-kdz-files-lg/) and then extract the image in the ZIP file contained payload file via "Payload Dumper Tool".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting data from a TWRP backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171202/extracting-data-from-a-twrp-backup)